# aws インスタンスタイプの vCPU, ECU, コア数の関係は？

Tags: aws

aws のあるインスタンスタイプがどれぐらいのCPU性能を持つかについて、 vCPU と ECU が一般的に利用されていること認識しています。

これらはそれぞれ何を表しますか？また、実際の CPU のコア数との関係は何ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[本家の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19254776/3090068) によると、 ECU は、 `1.0-1.2 GHz 2007 Opteron or 2007 Xeon processor` の処理能力を 1 とした時の相対的な性能を数値化したものです。同一型のプロセッサでコア数が２倍ならば、 ECU は２倍に成る認識です。

また、 `/proc/cpuinfo` を眺めてみるとどうやら

- vCPU == OS が認識するコア数 == hyper-threading が効いている場合は（仮想)物理コア数が２倍されている。

模様です。